# Django rest framework does model field validation before own validation

Tags: validation, django-rest-framework

I don't understand django rest framework validation process.
The [doc say](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validation-in-rest-framework) that validation is performed entirely on the serializer class.

However,
In the case of a PositiveIntegerField in a Model, when ModelSerializer receive a negative value, the model validation is processed before the custom ModelSerializer validate_myfield method.

```
class Blop(models.Model):
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class BlopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_quantity(self, value):
        return max(15, value)

    class Meta:
        model = Blop
```

if quantity if lesser than zero, validate_quantity is never called...

I've also tried :

- to use model "clean" method but rest framework doesn't use it.
- to disable min value validator in model by setting min_value to None, but it make rest framework to crash
- to force MinValueValidator in model field : `validators=[MinValueValidator(-math.inf, 'Minimum value is -Infinity')]`, it work, but it's too ugly

How can I do to have a serializer ensure non negative value in this case ?

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you are invoking the `serializer.is_valid()` method with no kwargs or `raise_exception=False`. 
With `raise_exception=True` the serializer raises `ValidationError`, if you pass invalid data.

For better understanding, lets take a look at the `Serializer.to_internal_value` method.

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    """
    Dict of native values <- Dict of primitive datatypes.
    """
    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        message = self.error_messages['invalid'].format(
            datatype=type(data).__name__
        )
        raise ValidationError({
            api_settings.NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY: [message]
        })

    ret = OrderedDict()
    errors = OrderedDict()
    fields = self._writable_fields

    for field in fields:
        validate_method = getattr(self, 'validate_' + field.field_name, None)
        primitive_value = field.get_value(data)
        try:
            validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
            if validate_method is not None:
                validated_value = validate_method(validated_value)
        except ValidationError as exc:
            errors[field.field_name] = exc.detail
        except DjangoValidationError as exc:
            errors[field.field_name] = list(exc.messages)
        except SkipField:
            pass
        else:
            set_value(ret, field.source_attrs, validated_value)

    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)

    return ret
```

As you can see here, firstly, the serializer invokes the `field.run_validation` method, which uses django-fields validators and they raise `DjangoValidationError` exception and because of that, your validation method is never invoked.

Comment: I'm using ModelViewSet with ModelSerializer can I configure something at this stage ? I know that model validation is triggerred before rest framework validation, this is my problem...

Comment: you can use `serializer.Meta.extra_kwargs` to set `min_value` for this field. I'm not sure, that this will work, but you can try. Also, you can try to set validators there, as far as I remember, they override default validators

Comment: Thanks, setting extra_kwargs quantity min_value to None, disable corresponding validation !